# How to equal height of <select> and <button> element with padding

Tags: html, css, height

I want to make both elements 'select' and 'button' have the same height.

[<kbd>**JS Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/dm58q/)

---

**HTML**

```
<select><option>...</option></select><button>Button</button>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-size:100%;
}

select, button {
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:.4em .6em;
    margin:0;
    //box-sizing:border-box; (did not help...)
}
```

---

[<kbd>**JS Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/dm58q/)

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

---

But it should look like this:

[image]

---

**How can I achieve the desired outcome with changing the CSS?**

Comment: desired img is missing. and in firefox both are of same height.

Comment: anyway, using border-box and setting the height explicitly will solve your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/dm58q/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select, button {
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin:0;

    padding:0 .6em; //updated
    height:2.3em; //new
    box-sizing:border-box; //new
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some bigger padding for button:

```
button{
   padding: 1px;
}
```

Just make sure in all browsers elements are shown equal. Form elements tends to be Browser specific, so they may wary. Better put dropdown above fake drowpdown image and make it with opacity = 0, in that way you will get dropdown appearance same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Give padding differently.. May be like this

```
select, button {
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin:0;
}

select {
    padding:.35em .6em;
}

button {
    padding:.4em .6em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define **height** as like this

```
select, button {
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:.4em .6em;
    margin:0;
    height:40px;  // add this line 
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dm58q/4/)**

Comment: OK, it works. But if I need to define a height, I have dependencies I don't want. Since I'm using LESSCSS, I might change the padding, but might forget to adjust the height. Also, the height needs to be in pixel, while the em is depending on the font... - Is there no smart solution to just "kill" this additional 1px padding of the select box?

Answer (score -1):

```
* {
    font-size: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}

select, button {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}

button {
    padding: 6px;
}
```